# Need to rotate back and forth repeatedly on hover Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, rotation, mouseover, repeat

Using jQuery rotate http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples to animate an object from 0 degrees to 40 degrees

Works fine on, mouseover, mouseout - but I need it to automatically loop an animation between the two points for as long as it is hovered

Need to finish by lunch for client...HELP!

```
    jQuery("#leafmealonepoint").rotate({ 
     bind: 
 { 
    mouseover : function() { 
        jQuery(this).rotate({animateTo:40})
    },
    mouseover : function() { 
        jQuery(this).rotate({animateTo:0})
    }
         }
```

UPDATE

ok so I'm trying to use setInterval like so - what's missing?

```
    function move(){
       jQuery('#leafmealonepoint').rotate({animateTo:40}, function(){
       jQuery(this).rotate({animateTo:0});
       });
     }    

    jQuery('#leafmealone').hover(
        function() {
      hoverInterval = setInterval(move, 1000);
        },
      function(){
    clearInterval(hoverInterval);
    }
    );
```

FURTHER UPDATE

```
     jQuery(function(){
         var leafmealone
         jQuery('#leafmealone').mouseenter(function(){
             leafmealone = setInterval(function()
             {jQuery('#leafmealonepoint').rotate({animateTo:40},
     jQuery('#leafmealonepoint').rotate({animateTo:0}))}, 1000);
         }).mouseleave(function(){clearInterval(leafmealone);
         });
     });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: as far as i can see **hoverInterval** is not a global variable, so it can't be cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to repeat that animation during mouse is on that element, you need a `setInterval()`, or this will execute animation once and will stop when completed, then mouse leave will execute again and stop again.

edit: Also you have 2 mouseover event, i think it's typo to hover you need a mouseout, or use `hover()` directly.

Comment: Im missing something simple with set interval...any ideas?

Comment: I added a dummy animation with your codes and it works, your problem might be about plugin that you are using. Check did you write plugin script's path right and check your html.

here is working example : http://jsfiddle.net/7AGNE/

Comment: yes, got the path right, as I'm using the same plugin elsewhere on the page - it rotates, to first position, but then doesn't return or move to the second position

Comment: It is about plugin i think, i look it's examples and doc and i didn't see that we can set animation time,it has a default value(i may be wrong didnt look every comment and page). Also to there is a callback for callback functions, as i said you need to search plugin but this seems working good but it might be a wrong solution. I hope it gives you idea how to solve: http://jsfiddle.net/7AGNE/2/ , as i said i dont have any idea about this plugin, this is just a temp. solution from examples you must take a look for it's doc.

Comment: You are welcome. As i see in your fiddle 'duration' is setting animation time in this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

try doing:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var leafmealone
    jQuery('#leafmealone')
    .mouseenter(function(){
        leafmealone = setInterval(function() {
            jQuery('#leafmealonepoint')
            .rotate({animateTo:40})
            .rotate({animateTo:0});
        }, 1000);
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
        clearInterval(leafmealone);
    });
});
```

I'm not familiar with the rotate method, but that is usually how animations are done/chained.

Comment: v close. Figured it out though - will post full answer in 8 hrs http://jsfiddle.net/nyFjP/20/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution

```
 function leafmealone() {
        jQuery('#leafmealonepoint').stop().rotate({ angle:0, animateTo: 40, duration:600, callback: function() {
            jQuery('#leafmealonepoint').stop().rotate({ animateTo: 0, duration:600});
            }
        });
}

    jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#leafmealone').hover(function(){
leafmealone();
hoverInterval = setInterval(leafmealone, 1200);
    }, function(){
      clearInterval(hoverInterval);
    });
   })
```

​